# How to fix error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled?

Tags: swift, github-actions, code-signing, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package manager project and I am trying to run unit tests with Fastlane on GitHub actions.
My fastfile looks like

```
  desc('Unit test with spm')
  lane :spm_test do
    scan(
      workspace: ".swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace",
      package_path: ".",
      device: "iPhone 11",
      scheme: SCHEME,
      clean: false,
      code_coverage: true,
      derived_data_path: ".build"
    )
  end
```

But time to time I am getting this error,
`error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'Scheme_Scheme' from project 'Scheme')` - same for multiple dependencies and test target then finally

```
Testing failed:
    Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled.
    Testing cancelled because the build failed.
```

Last part of build log

```
3499 ▸ Build Succeeded
3500 2022-04-08 10:53:25.292 xcodebuild[2468:12022] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-19466/IDEFoundation/Execution/RunContextManager/IDERunContextManager.m:823
3501 Details:  Error deleting scheme: Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.
3502 Object:   <IDERunContextManager: 0x7fdaacb72e50>
3503 Method:   -deleteRunContexts:completionQueue:completionBlock:
3504 Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fdaa97170e0>{number = 1, name = main}
3505 Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
3506 2022-04-08 10:53:25.293 xcodebuild[2468:12022] could not delete old scheme: Error Domain=DVTCustomDataStoringErrors Code=0 "Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.}
3507
3508 ❌   error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'MyProjectDependency_MyProjectDependency' from project 'MyProjectDependency')
3509
3510
3511
3512 ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'MyProject_MyProject' from project 'MyProject')
3513
3514
3515
3516 ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'MyProjectTests' from project 'MyProject')
3517
3518
3519
3520 ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'MyProject_MyProjectTests' from project 'MyProject')
3521
3522
3523 Testing failed:
3524    Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled.
3525    Testing cancelled because the build failed.
3526
3527 ** TEST FAILED **
```

This is running perfectly when I run on my local machine. I have another set of tests that uses a normal Xcode project(not SPM) that also works fine.

What could be the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

UPD: This is happening only with Xcode 13.x,  Xcode 12.x is working fine.

Comment: Does your Swift package have bundled resources? I'm also running into the "Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving" error on GH Actions, but it seems to stop as soon as I remove bundled resources. Also, this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72741060/171089 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73152796/171089