# xcodebuild error: `Error deleting scheme: Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.`

Tags: testing, xcodebuild

I'm trying to test a Swift package using `xcodebuild`. The command is:

```s
/Applications/Xcode_13.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild test -scheme BokenEngine -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11" -enableCodeCoverage YES -derivedDataPath .DerivedData
```

I can execute it on my machine with macOS 12.4 and Xcode 13.4.1 but when I try to execute the same command on a GitHub runner I get this error:

```s
2022-06-24 08:05:12.553 xcodebuild[1861:25223] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-20103/IDEFoundation/Execution/RunContextManager/IDERunContextManager.m:823
Details:  Error deleting scheme: Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.
Object:   <IDERunContextManager: 0x600000fd97a0>
Method:   -deleteRunContexts:completionQueue:completionBlock:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x6000028ec400>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2022-06-24 08:05:12.554 xcodebuild[1861:25223] could not delete old scheme: Error Domain=DVTCustomDataStoringErrors Code=0 "Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.}
```

Lint to the error: https://github.com/boken-engine/boken-engine/runs/7037978166?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:56
More info: https://github.com/boken-engine/boken-engine/issues/131

Comment: Does your Swift package have bundled resources? I'm also running into the "Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving" error on GH Actions, but it seems to stop as soon as I remove bundled resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on GitLab CI, but it only started occurring for me when I updated the build machines to Xcode 14; I had never seen the issue on earlier versions of Xcode.

For my case, it seems the solution was to commit the `.xcscheme` file for that Swift package to the remote repository. In order to generate the scheme file, I had to open the "Manage Schemes" window in Xcode and click the "Autocreate Schemes Now" button.