Github Action started failing for the Swift Package with `could not delete old scheme` error
I am building a Swift Package via Github Action, which was working fine previously, the only change I did in a package is added custom font files in Resources folder,
            resources: [
                .copy("Resources/Fonts")
            ],

These changes were merged into the branch, and now have started getting the failure logs as mentioned below for the Github Action,
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x6000018fc3c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2024-05-30 02:54:26.569 xcodebuild[3887:22933] could not delete old scheme: Error Domain=DVTCustomDataStoringErrors Code=0 "Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot modify data because the process disallows saving.}

xcodebuild[3887:22933] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot11/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-22269/IDEFoundation/Execution/Schemes/IDEScheme.m:958
Details:  no action returned for command <IDEConcretePrimitiveSchemeCommand:0x600000085140:Run> (self.testSchemeAction is (null))
Object:   <IDEScheme: 0x7f918702fde0>
Method:   -buildConfigurationForSchemeCommand:
Thread:   <_NSMainThread: 0x6000018fc3c0>{number = 1, name = main}

Based on the solution  have made the scheme related changes in a temp branch, and Github Action built the package, but I am not clear why font file is causing scheme related issues.

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045248/833395
